# Authentication Flows With Redux In React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      {/* {console.log('>>>>>', token)} */}
      {token === null ? (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
           <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigation" component={TabNavigation} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigation" component={TabNavigation} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ListUsers" component={ListUsers} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat} />
          <Stack.Screen name="FirstPage" component={FirstPage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Calendar" component={Calendar} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
```

//I Have Set This Code For Authentication Flows Mean If i have Token Then It will Navigate To DashBoard With the help of redux But There's One Issue When I am Tring To SignUp It's Saying Please Add SignUp Screen in Stack, But I have already added there, Every Thing Is Working Fine But Now I'm Not Able To Navigate To DashBoard On SignUp Button. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

is your token retrieve from a selector from redux?
if true:

1. on signup button, after you signup with success, you need only to call an action to save the token. you don't have to call navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
2. if you save the token on redux, automatically your render switch to logged stack navigator.

you can read more about it:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/